# ifeq conditional and in Makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

Trying to do a conditional compilation on Makefile. If the all three conditions(aka matches) are satisfied then go ahead with compiling certain subdirectory else do something else.

```
MATCH1 := $(if $(strip $(VAR1)),$(patsubst 6000,,$(VAR1)),NO)
MATCH2 := $(if $(strip $(VAR2)),$(patsubst cp,,$(VAR2)),NO)
MATCH3 := $(if $(strip $(VAR3)),$(patsubst 100g,,$(VAR3)),NO)

ifneq ($(and $(MATCH1)[,$(MATCH2)[,$(MATCH3)]])).   <<< error here
do-something
else 
do-something-else
endif
```

The code gives me error at the above mentioned line saying
"Makefile:26: *** invalid syntax in conditional. "

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misreading the syntax example.  In most technical manuals the characters [ and ] surround optional things: parts that can be omitted.  They aren't meant to be inserted directly into the text.

Also you need to have two things to compare, here you only have one (the `$(and ...)` function).

Also I don't know why you're adding a period to the end.  Maybe that's not there in your real version.

You should write this as:

```
ifneq (,$(and $(MATCH1),$(MATCH2),$(MATCH3)))
```

note the comma at the beginning: you're comparing the empty string to the result of the `$(and ..)` function (which will be empty if any of the `$(MATCHx)` variables are empty.